# get_categories order by last post

Tags: wordpress

What is the best and shortest way in Wordpress to [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) ordered by last posted article?

Means that categories with recent posts should appear first, is it available somehow?

Comment: I would do it first retrieving all the categories than loop through the categories and get the last post based on publish date storing it in an array, then order the resulting array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it:

```
function get_sorted_categories( $order_by = 'id', $args = array() ){
    global $wpdb;

    $category = get_categories( $args );

    $order = [
        'id' => 'post.ID',
        'date' => 'post.post_date',
        'modified' => 'post.post_modified',
    ];

    $order_by = $order[ $order_by ];

    $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT tax.term_id FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy` tax
    INNER JOIN `{$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships` rel ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_id
    INNER JOIN `{$wpdb->prefix}posts` post ON rel.object_id = post.ID WHERE tax.taxonomy = 'category' AND post.post_type = 'post' AND post.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY {$order_by} DESC");

    $sort = array_flip( array_unique( wp_list_pluck( $q, 'term_id' ) ) );

    usort( $category, function( $a, $b ) use ( $sort, $category ) {
        if( isset( $sort[ $a->term_id ], $sort[ $b->term_id ] ) && $sort[ $a->term_id ] != $sort[ $b->term_id ] )
            $res = ($sort[ $a->term_id ] > $sort[ $b->term_id ]) ? 1 : -1;
        else if( !isset( $sort[ $a->term_id ] ) && isset( $sort[ $b->term_id ] ) )
            $res = 1;
        else if( isset( $sort[ $a->term_id ] ) && !isset( $sort[ $b->term_id ] ) )
            $res = -1;
        else
            $res = 0;

        return $res;
    } );

    return $category;
}

print_r( get_sorted_categories() );
print_r( get_sorted_categories('date') );
print_r( get_sorted_categories('modified') );
```

Get categories order by (post ID | post date | post modified date). Without any loop and fast!

Comment: I modified the code so that I can add some `$args` to `get_categories()` but it is breaking the sort process, any idea how to do this? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @tinyCoder. code updated for handle exceptions ( hide empty => false ). but about other `$args`, are you need pass `$args` to `get_categories()` function in this problem really?

Comment: Thanks for the modification, I only need to show empty categories and exclude one category.

Comment: @tinyCoder code updated and support `show_empty` & `exclude` args now. try it again ...

Comment: Man, you are awesome!! super function, I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: That is gr8... now I'm looking in how to reorder categories based on this... perhaps by a 'post_published' hook to update `wp_terms.term_order`... any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to loop through all of your posts ordered by `post_date` and then save the categories to an array. You can then loop through the categories and display them. They will be in order.

Something like this:

```
<?php

// Initiate array
$cats = array();

// Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' = 'post_date'.
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

// The query
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// The loop
if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();

        // Get the term object
        $term = get_the_category();

        // Make sure the term doesn't already exist in the array
        if(!array_key_exists($term[0]->ID, $cats)) {
            // Add the terms to the array
            $cats[$term[0]->ID] = $term;
        }
    }
}

foreach($cats as $cid => $cat) {
    // Loop through the categories here
}
?>
```

Of course, as mentioned in the comment above you could also do it the other way around and loop through the categories first then sort the array. Something like this could do:

```
<?php

// Initiate array
$cats = get_categories();
$recent_cats = array();

foreach($cats as $k => $cat) {
    // Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' = 'post_date'.
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'cat' => $cat->term_id
    );

    // The query
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // The loop
    if($query->have_posts()) {
        while($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $date_str = strtotime(the_date());
            if(!array_key_exists($date_str, $recent_cats)) {
                $recent_cats[$date_str] = $cat->name;
            }
        }
    }
}

krsort($recent_cats);

// Loop through $recent_cats here

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! my website has thousands of posts and tens of categories, sure that will affect the function, please note that you have a typo as `'orderby' = 'post_date'.` should be `'orderby' => 'post_date',` and the code returned `array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer`.