# get_categories order by post with custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

i have some research and found this [get_categories order by last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100515/get-categories-order-by-last-post)

It's almost what I want, but i want the post order by custom field(created by plugin Advanced Custom Fields), let say the posts order by the date(custom field), then the categories with greatest custom field value post will appear first, is it available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
function get_sorted_categories( $custom_field, $args = array() ){
    global $wpdb;

    $category = get_categories( $args );

    $custom_field = esc_sql( $custom_field );

    $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT tax.term_id FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy` tax
    INNER JOIN `{$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships` rel ON rel.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_id
    INNER JOIN `{$wpdb->prefix}posts` post ON rel.object_id = post.ID 
    INNER JOIN `{$wpdb->prefix}postmeta` meta ON meta.post_id = post.ID AND meta.meta_key = '{$custom_field}'
    WHERE tax.taxonomy = 'category' AND post.post_type = 'post' AND post.post_status = 'publish' AND  ORDER BY meta.meta_value DESC");

    $sort = array_flip( array_unique( wp_list_pluck( $q, 'term_id' ) ) );

    usort( $category, function( $a, $b ) use ( $sort, $category ) {
        if( isset( $sort[ $a->term_id ], $sort[ $b->term_id ] ) && $sort[ $a->term_id ] != $sort[ $b->term_id ] )
            $res = ($sort[ $a->term_id ] > $sort[ $b->term_id ]) ? 1 : -1;
        else if( !isset( $sort[ $a->term_id ] ) && isset( $sort[ $b->term_id ] ) )
            $res = 1;
        else if( isset( $sort[ $a->term_id ] ) && !isset( $sort[ $b->term_id ] ) )
            $res = -1;
        else
            $res = 0;

        return $res;
    } );

    return $category;
}

print_r( get_sorted_categories('CUSTOM_FIELD_KEY') );
```

Just pass the custom field key to function.