# Wordpress: $categories as $category - sort by date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, categories

I've got the following code to show all categories and the last post in a category - using Wordpress:

```
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
$category_link = sprintf( 
   '<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
    esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
    esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ),
    $category->name ) ),
    esc_html( $category->name )
                        );

global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1,  'category' => $category->term_id);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
$newpost="<a href=".get_the_permalink()."><b>".get_the_title()."</b></a>
$newdate=get_the_date();
endforeach;
```

Right now the categories are sorted by alphabet.

Is there a way to sort them by the date of the last post?

I thought about putting an argument to the first line like:

```
 foreach( $categories as $category sort by ... )
```

But I couldn't find a way.

Maybe you can help?

Thank you for your help!

Just found this working code:
[get_categories order by last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100515/get-categories-order-by-last-post)

Answer (score -2):

You can sort records of $categories like :

```
$categories = array('post_status'=>'publish','post_type' => 'test', 'orderby' => 
'date', 'order' => 'DESC','paged' => $paged );
```

Comment: so that you need to do loop only, because your variable will filtered already by date in descending

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, since that answer looks like the best solution from where I'm standing, considering how vague the question is. However, that comment should have been appended to the question itself.

Comment: Why would I try your solution ?

Comment: I don't understand this code, much less how it solves the question. why are you putting the args for get_posts in $categories?

Comment: Thank you for your responses.

I've just found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100515/get-categories-order-by-last-post

Worked for me!