# How do I sort categories Wordpress blogs by recent post date?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hey everyone I am attempting to order my categories by most recent post date. This means when I go to add a post and mark it under that category I want the category to show at the top from most recent to old. Also if you have a way to hide a certain category id I would love to know how. I'm new with PHP and would love some help, thanks everyone.

CODE:

```
<?php
         $cat_args = array(
     'orderby' => 'date',
     'post_type' => 'products',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'child_of' => 0,
         );

    $categories =   get_categories($cat_args);

    foreach($categories as $category) {
         echo '<dl>';
         echo '<h3 class="category-name">' . $category->name.'</h3>';

            $post_args = array(
             'numberposts' => -1,
             'category' => $category->term_id
         );

         $posts = get_posts($post_args);

         foreach($posts as $post) {
         ?>
                 <dd><a class="article" target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('article_link') ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><span class="news-source"> - <?php the_field('news_source') ?></span><p class="important"><?php the_field('important') ?></p></dd>
         <?php
         }
         //echo '<dd class="view-all"> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>View all posts in ' . $category->name.'</a></dd>';
         echo '</dl>';
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: Did you tried change `'order' => 'ASC'` to `'order' => 'DESC'`?

Comment: @Zavarock I just tried that and it still shows the post down the list. The category did not move to the top.

Comment: Hmm... I think you are looking for `'orderby' => 'post_date'`. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100515/get-categories-order-by-last-post

Comment: @Zavarock So I did add that and it still does not want to work. That is so odd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get recent posts and from that get categories after getting categories run loop through categori it.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '-1' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
         echo '<dl>';
         echo '<h3 class="category-name">' . get_the_category_list( ', ', '', $recent["ID"] ).'</h3>';
     $post_args = array(
             'numberposts' => -1,
             'category' => $recent["ID"]
         );

         $posts = get_posts($post_args);
         foreach($posts as $post) {
         ?>
                 <dd><a class="article" target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('article_link') ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><span class="news-source"> - <?php the_field('news_source') ?></span><p class="important"><?php the_field('important') ?></p></dd>
         <?php
         }
         //echo '<dd class="view-all"> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>View all posts in ' . $category->name.'</a></dd>';
         echo '</dl>';
    }
    wp_reset_query();
```